# Multi level inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to access and modify data that is in a parent class which is a child of another class.
I've a parent class

```
class GrandParent {
    protected $data = 1;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}
```

Below is my first level child

```
class Child extends GrandParent {
    protected $c1Data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->c1Data = parent::getData();
        $this->c1Data = 2;
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->c1Data;
    }
}
```

If I try to instantiate the `Child` class and do `getData()`, I get 2 which is normal. I've another class that inherits `Child`.

```
class GrandChild extends Child {
    protected $c2Data;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->c2Data = parent::getData();
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->c2Data;
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I try to instantiate `GrandChild` I and get the data I'm getting `null`. Is it possible to make my `GrandChild` class inherit `$c1Data = 2` and work with it. I want also to be able to use the `Child` and `GrandParent` classes on their own and not be abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `NULL` because `__constructor` of a `Child` class is not invoked and that's why `c1Data` property is **NOT SET**. You should explicitly call for `Child` `__constructor`:

```
class GrandChild extends Child {
    protected $c2Data;

    public function __construct() {
        // here
        parent::__construct();

        $this->c2Data = parent::getData();
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->c2Data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add two integers and display the result with Multi
Level Inheritance in PHP.

```
    <?php 
    /*
    Inheritance:
    multiple classes
    Parent class/child class
    senior and junior
    child class extends some data or functions of parent class
    child class has its own functions
    child class can access all public and protected data and functions
    */
    //Multi Level Inheritance Every class extends other class
    //Parent Class
    class A{
        //data
        var $a;
        function setA()
        {
            $this->a=10;        
        }
    }
    //child class
    class B extends A{
        var $b;
        function setB()
        {
            $this->b=20;
        }
        
        
    }
    class Addition extends B{
        function add()
        {
            $this->setA();
            $this->setB();
            return $this->a+$this->b;       
        }
    }
    class Print1 extends Addition{
        function print()
        {
            $this->add();
            print("a=".$this->a);
            print("<br/>b=".$this->b);
            print("<br/>Addtion:".$this->add());
            
        }
    }
    //make object
    $obj1=new Print1();
    $obj1->print();

    /*
    Make Subtraction, multiplication and division classes and print the values as

    a=10
    b=20
    Addtion=30
    Subtraction=-10
    Multiplication=200
    Division:0.5



    */
    ?>
```